# LUKS: Decrypt home directory

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, encryption, luks

I have Ubuntu with encrypted home directory. Today I worked with Ubuntu but free space was running out. After reboot laptop, on the half progress of encryption I start see balck screen with steady cursor. Now I booted from liveUSB.

UPD: How to decrypt home directory from liveUSB?

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 0):

You can decrypt the partition from the live usb. Just go to the "Disks" application, then select the drive and the partition that you encrypted with luks. You will be prompted to enter a password

Comment: I encrypted just home directory and swap (not all partition) I can mount it and see unencrypted data, but in this case I need decrypt home directory even with prompt to enter password.

Comment: If i understand correctly what you want is to unencrypt the partition so it no longer asks for a password. if thats the case it seems that it is better to backup your data and reformat the partitions.